# NavigationLink doesn't work when View is embedded in a modal sheet

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, navigationview, swiftui-navigationstack

Weird problem.
I have a view called `SecondView` which has a `NavigationLink` like so:

```
struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                //PowerUp Section
                Section {
                    VStack {
                        NavigationLink (destination: Powerup()) {
                            Text("2")
                        }
                        .isDetailLink(false)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This view is embedded in a modal view.
The `NavigationLink` works fine when I preview `SecondView` on **Xcode** but doesn't when I preview the modal sheet.
Doesn't work on an actual device or simulator too.
Looks like a hierarchy problem or something like this.
Can someone tell me where I'm wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-solved the problem.
I was embedding `SecondView` in the modal in the wrong way.
The view should be wrapped in a `NavigationView` and a `NavigationStack` first.
Maybe it's helpful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Since the old `NavigationLink(destination:)` has some severe limitations, you are supposed to use `NavigationLink(value:)` and `.navigationDestination(for:)` when using the new [`NavigationStack`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack), e.g.

```
NavigationStack {
    List(parks) { park in
        NavigationLink(park.name, value: park)
    }
    .navigationDestination(for: Park.self) { park in
        ParkDetails(park: park)
    }
}
```